# How to dump data owned by postgres in case of lack of privileges for writing

Tags: database, postgresql, dump, pg-dump

I have DB owned by `postgres`, and I need to dump it, but `postgres` user does not have rights to write. 
So it boils down to login to DB as `postgres` but under different user in OS. How can I do that? I tried `-U postgres` but get an error even without password prompt. Basically I seek for `mysql -u root -p' in Postgres.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dump to the standard output, and have another OS user  write to the file.

Assuming you're `root`:

```
# (su postgres -c 'pg_dump -U postgres dbname') > /path/to/backup.sql
```

The resulting file will created and written by `root`.

Comment: @Gill: you wrote that `postgres` user lacks rights to write, but is it the case that `root` also can't write anywhere? You'll have to find a directory with write permissions, otherwise only a remote dump may be possible.

Comment: A little more pretty version: `sudo -u postgres pg_dump -Fp database_name > dump.sql`